# Alamofire Swift 2.0 <unknown>:0: error: tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'Response<String, NSError>'

Tags: alamofire

I am using Manger class for request. When I compile it shows

```
<unknown>:0: error: tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'Response<String, NSError>' Error`.
```

Its working fine in old Swift `Xcode 6.*`. But in `Xcode 7.*` its not working.

```
let aManager = Manager.sharedInstance
    aManager.request(.GET, URLStrings.BASE_URL + URLStrings.CATEGORIES)
        .responseString { _, _, result in
            print("Response String: \(result.value)")
        }
        .responseJSON { _, _, result in
            print("Response JSON: \(result.value)")
    }
```

On clicking responseString it shows ?
Kindly Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I supposed that you are using the 3.0+ Alamofire. 
I encounter this problem recently, here is my solution:
for you code replace `_, _, result` to `response` and query the response data by `response.data` or `response.result.value`

For more information about the new response structure, you can check the official document here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Hope these helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the Alamofire 3.0.0-beta.1 pre-release. You should switch back to Alamofire 2.0.2 (the latest release) until we have all the documentation and migration guides up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code in to this form. Now What I have to do is Convert data to JSon Object my self. But its working now for me.

```
let aManager = Manager.sharedInstance
    aManager.request(.GET, URLStrings.BASE_URL + URLStrings.CATEGORIES )
        .response {
            (request, response, data, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print("GET REQUEST: \(request?.description)")
                print("GET REQUEST: \(response.statusCode)")
                if response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 {
               }
           }
           else {
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I check the official document here: [Response Serializers](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

In the document, find **Response Serializers**, read the example code, I post it in here:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)     // prints detailed description of all response properties

         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

Hope it can helps you~